# check if file with certain file extension present in folder using batch script

Tags: batch-file, file-extension, file-exists

I want to check a certain file extension in the folder using batch script

Its like,

```
if exist <any file with extension .elf>
  do something
else
  do something else
```

Here file name may be anything but only extension(.elf) is important

Comment: if should be like this **if exist *.elf do ( file exist - do something )**, you should use **do** keyword

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the simplest case the batch language includes a construct for this task

```dos
if exist *.elf (
    :: file exists - do something 
) else (
    :: file does not exist - do something else
)
```

where the `if exist` will test for existence of an element in the current or indicate folder that matches the indicated name/wildcard expression.

While in this case it seems you will not need anything else, you should take into consideration that `if exist` makes no difference between a file and a folder. If the name/wildcard expression that you are using matches a folder name, `if exists` will evaluate to true.

How to ensure we are testing for a file? The easiest solution is to use the `dir` command to search for files (excluding folders). If it fails (raises errorlevel), there are no files matching the condition.

```dos
dir /a-d *.elf >nul 2>&1 
if errorlevel 1 (
    :: file does not exist - do something
) else (
    :: file exists - do something else
)
```

Or, using conditional execution (just a little abreviation for the above code)

```dos
dir /a-d *.elf >nul 2>&1 && (
    :: file does exist - do something
) || ( 
    :: file does not exist - do something else 
)
```

What it does is execute a `dir` command searching for `*.elf` , excluding folders (`/a-d`) and sending all the output to `nul` device, that is, discarding the output. If errorlevel is raised, no matching file has been found.

Comment: if should be like this **if exist *.elf do ( file does exist - do something )**, you should use **do** keyword

Comment: @MȍhǟmmǟdȘamȋm, **no, it should not**. In batch files `for` command needs the `do` clause but `if` command syntax doesn't include a `do` clause.

Comment: **if exist *.elf do** this is working for me fine, **if** with **do**, without **do** in my case it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

as easy as you can think:

```
if exist *.elf echo yes
```